# Setting a boundary based on stored variable?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

In my database, there's a field named `comments` that says how many comments are in a post. Until now, I've been using `LIMIT` with that specific amount while retrieving all the comments, but I worry that it may lead to inaccuracies if it's a popular post in which comments are added/deleted quickly.

My question is, while retrieving comments, let's say, is an upper boundary good to use? Do websites just query the entire table? I used `LIMIT` because I thought it would be a tad more efficient, but is there really a difference?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Most applications query what they need. If you're doing paged output, you would use LIMIT with the page size. If you're showing everything, then no limit.

Answer (score 0):

You can query the first `30` comments (lets say) using `LIMIT`, and the total comments that belong to your post using `COUNT`. Now, build up pagination links based on that count.

Now, whenever the user clicks the page number `n`, use AJAX to fetch the new comments and replace the existing comments. Use `LIMIT` along with `OFFSET` for this purpose.

This way, you won't need to pull up all your comments for that post in one go, and at the same time, will be able to provide your users with the required comments, if they need to read more..

Most popular sites, and I think WordPress, as well, uses this process.

---

**UPDATE**

If you are using `load more` kind of thing, you do not need to even run a `COUNT` query. Just load the first 30 comments, and an ajax based solution to fetch the next 30 queries, and rinse and repeat, unless the sql returns empty results.

The offset should be incremented by `30` (in this case) on every ajax request, but the limit should stay at `30` each time.

Comment: It isn't really pages, it's a "load more" kind of thing. So when I scroll down and click "load more," I send an AJAX with the last id loaded and the offset? But again, back on the offset thing, what if there are rapid changes? Shouldn't the offset always be `30`?

Comment: So basically, you DO end up querying the entire table. Thanks :).

Comment: No, you do not query your entire `comments` table. Use a `where` clause to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` and [`FOUND_ROWS()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows) instead of storing number of comments.

Example of select statement:

```sql
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *
FROM comments
WHERE post_id = ?
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT 0, 10
```

When you run this query, you will get your comments, and right after that run query:

```sql
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

than will return number of comments in previous query without LIMIT.

Comment: OP is not asking the number of comments in the previous query, but instead, a mechanism to show comments in an optimal way.

Comment: @Stoic: my advice was for not storing number of comments in post table, and not running 2 queries like you advised (with COUNT()) for fetching number for all comments. About how to show comments, he already said he uses LIMIT (I supposed with paging), thats why I didn't comment on that, since I should done the same.

Comment: @Glavić: he could use a mechanism such as `counter_cache` to counter the performance issues with `COUNT`. Also, I think your solution uses 2 queries, as well. :)

Comment: @Shahar: use what you think is right for your project, both cases are correct ;)

Comment: @Glavić Even with `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()`, are there cases where storing is more efficient or do you never store those things? For example, Twitter followers - does Twitter actually count how many followers there are every time you visit a page or do they just have the number stored?

Comment: @Shahar: I think they will have the numbers stored somewhere. That is definitely the more efficient way of doing this. Read on Google about `counter_cache`

Comment: @Stoic: True, but it looks nicer ;)) Don't get me wrong, I also think that using `COUNT()` method is faster method of doing this, but why should every SO answer be the same ;)